# Change activetab via props Vue

Tags: vue.js, tabs, sidebar, vue-cli, simplemodal

I'm using vue-cli and I have a Charts component with tabs. I'd like to change the active tab based on opening a modal in a sidebar.

```js
<a>
      <div v-if="showModal">
        <div class="overlay" @click.self="showModal = false;">
         <Charts :activetab=1></Charts>
        </div>  
          <span @click="showModal = !showModal;" >
           {{ showModal ? "Close" : "Options"}} 
          </span>
      </div>
</a>

<a>  
      <div v-if="showModal">
        <div class="overlay" @click.self="showModal = false;">
            <Charts :activetab=2></Charts>
        </div>
        <span @click="showModal = !showModal;">
          {{ showModal ? "Close" : "Settings" }} 
        </span>
  </div>
</a>


<script>
data () {
    return {
      activetab: '',
```

I'm passing activetab as a props to the Charts component but when I click on Options in the sidebar menu it defaults to activetab = 2 even though I set it to = 1.
Any ideas would appreciated, thanks!

### Update

Charts component that sets activetab:

```js
<div class="tabs">
        <a v-on:click="activetab=1" v-bind:class="[ activetab === 1 ? 'active' : '' ]">Options</a>
        <a v-on:click="activetab=2" v-bind:class="[ activetab === 2 ? 'active' : '' ]">Settings</a>
    </div>
    
   
<div class="content">
        <div v-if="activetab === 1" class="tabcontent">
           <Options></Options>
        </div>
        <div v-if="activetab === 2" class="tabcontent">
            <Settings></Settings>
        </div>

<script>
export default {
  props:['activetab'],
```

### Edit

I updated with emit from child component but it's only showing the last activetab for all.

Child Component:

```js
methods: {

    updateActive1() {
      this.$emit('updateActive1', 1)
    },
     updateActive2() {
      this.$emit('updateActive2', 2)
    },
  },
  mounted()
  {
    this.updateActive1()
    this.updateActive2()
  },
```

Parent:

```js
<a>  
 <Charts :activetab=activetab @updateActive1="newActive1($event)"></Charts>
</a>
<a>    
  <Charts :activetab=activetab  @updateActive2="newActive2($event)"></Charts>
</a>


<script>
methods:{
    newActive1: function(event1) {
        this.activetab = event1; 
    },newActive2: function(event2) {
        this.activetab = event2;
    },
}
```

Only newActive2 seems to run for both.

### Fixed

I added `newActive()` to the `<a>` tag and now it's working!

```js
<a @click="newActive(2)"> 
<Charts :activetab=activetab></Charts>
```

Comment: Where is the code that sets `activetab`?

Comment: @DecadeMoon I will update with it

Comment: Props are one-way and cannot be directly modified by the child component; instead the child must emit an event to the parent if it wants to tell the parent to update the prop.

Comment: Thank you! So I should set up something like @click="sendActive()", sendActive( this.$emit('activetab, 1'))? Not sure if that makes sense, been trying to learn $emit but still trying to understand how to implement it.

Comment: I got emit working but still trying to figure out how I can change the activetab value depending on which sidebar menu item I click on